# WebService error when accessed from PowerBuilder 12 aplication

Tags: wcf, powerbuilder

We have a WCF service developed in C# which is being used by several .Net and PowerBuilder applications.

When a document is scanned users can preview the scanned document on the application window and when the save button is clicked, the WCF service is called and the document get stored in our repository.

The above functionality is working absolutely fine for single page scans and if we scan multiple pages, we are getting error saying "The definition of the method signature in the web proxy is wrong-the data doesn't match the parameter"

Interesting part is, whether it is single page document or multi page, it calls the same method.

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in the message. When you call the service to scan multiple pages, the data it returns doesn't match the contract. Most likely, the contract says it returns one of whatever represents the page, but the service is sending more than one.